# How can I set the value of a dictionary element to the result of a keyword in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I know that I can access a single element from a dictionary object with this format ${dict['KEY']}.  Like this:

```
|   | Log | ${dict['KEY']} |
```

And I can set a regular old scalar like this:

```
|   | ${scalar}= | RFKeyword | "Yowp"
```

But if I try to set a dictionary element like this

```
|   | ${dict['KEY']}= | RFKeyword | "Yowp"
```

I get  "RFKeyword", "Yowp" in the variable, rather than the result of what RFKeyword produces when processing "Yowp" like I do with this

```
|   | ${scalar}= | RFKeyword | "Yowp"
```

Assistance please

Answer (score 13):

As you probably have figured out, you can't assign to a dictionary from a keyword. You need to very specifically follow the dictionary syntax. you can only return variables to lists or scalars.

Robot framework isn't a fully fledged programming language, and it shouldn't be. By using an intermediate scalar, non-technical testers should be better able to understand what it is doing.

I added this since a google search for "robot framework dictionary" has this question high up in the list.
Just create dictionaries with:

```
Create dictionary | ${my_dict} | a | b
```

Add to dictionaries with:

```
set to dictionary | ${my_dict} | c | d
```

And retrieve from dictionaries with:

```
${my_dict["a"]}
```

Or, if you need to not fail:

```
${my_dict.get('non-key','default value')}
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need to rearrange the way you call it.  So for your keyword where you want the returned data to go into your dictionary you need to do the following:

```
${scalar}= | RFKeyword | "Yowp"
Set To Dictionary  | ${dict}  |  KEY    | ${scalar}
```

Comment: But I don't want the scalar at all. I want the result of the keyword to go directly into a dictionary.